# Splitting a String with different inputs Java

Tags: java

Input = computer science: harvard university, cambridge (EXAMPLE)

Prompt: Use a String method twice, to find the locations of the colon and the comma.
Use a String method to extract the major and store it into a new String.
Use a String method to extract the university and store it into a new String.
Use a String method to extract the city and store it into a new String.
Display the major, university, and city in reverse, as shown below, followed by a newline.

I was thinking I could just use substring(); but the input entered from the user varies and so the indexes are all different. I am still learning and am stumped on how to do this one. Does substring let you somehow use it without knowing the specific index? Or do I have to use a whole different method? Any help would be awesome. BTW this is HW.

Comment: You are correct that you can use substring, but first you need to use a different String method to find the position of the `:` and `,` characters. The list of available methods is [in the official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#method.summary), which one do you think sounds like the best candidate to return a result you can use as input for `substring()`?

Comment: (and yes, I could just tell you, but since this is a homework assignment I think it will help you more if you know how and where to find the relevant information in the docs)

Comment: Thanks for this I already was using IndexOf but It wasn't letting me use the ASCII numbers for the comma and colon cause they were out of the length of the string. But I figured it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input string has format: `<major>: <university>, <city>`

String has a set of `indexOf()` methods to find the position of a [character](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))/[substring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) (returns -1 if the character/substring is not found) and `substring` to retrieve a subpart of the input [from index](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) or [between a pair of indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)).

Also, [`String::trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#trim()) may be used to get rid of leading/trailing whitespaces.

```java
String input = "computer science: harvard university, cambridge";

int colonAt = input.indexOf(':');
int commaAt = input.indexOf(',');
// or int commaAt = input.indexOf(',', colonAt + 1); to make sure comma occurs after the colon

String major = null;
String university = null;
String city = null;
if (colonAt > -1 && commaAt > -1) {
    major = input.substring(0, colonAt);
    university = input.substring(colonAt + 1, commaAt).trim();
    city = input.substring(commaAt + 1).trim();
}

System.out.printf("Major: '%s', Univ: '%s', City: '%s'%n", major, university, city);
```

Output:

```
Major: 'computer science', Univ: 'harvard university', City: 'cambridge'
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I ended up just using indexOf and substring. I was having issues with reading the comma and semicolon because the ASCII of the colon is 54, and it wouldn't let me use that number cause it was out of the length of the string. But I just did what you did and put the comma and colon in a whole separate variable. Worked like a charm. The trim method was also great, but I didn't use the if statement.

Comment: @Wolfie, if the answer is helpful, you can upvote/accept it as described in Help Center: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)